# How can I change a string date eg "2019-07-26" to "26 July 2019" in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Would like to get some help if possible regarding the problem said in the title.

Assuming I can't use new Date since I will get the date from a string already

Comment: Hello. Please specify what exactly you want the answer to look like using M,D, and Y, like "DD MMMM YYYY." Because using `new Date("2019-07-26").toDateString()` might be what you want, but I can't tell because your question is a bit vague.

Comment: Exactly, although I want it to return 26 Jul 2019 instead of the Jul 26 2019 as the it is the default